Was Seven of Nine named after My Living Doll's AF-709?
The claim is made here, but I am not sure I buy it.

Not for the first time, and certainly not for the last, Star Trek crossed over with a DC comics property. In this case, Seven of Nine was inspired, in part, by Catwoman. Julie Newmar, who had appeared in the Adam West Batman television series, also appeared in the Original Series episode Friday's Child. Here, she played Eleen, the heavily pregnant inhabitant of Capella IV.
Newmar had also appeared in a short-lived sitcom named My Living Doll. The show, which ran for 25 episodes between 1964 and 1965, focused on Dr. Bob MacDonald and Rhoda - a lifelike android, played by Newmar. She had the sub designation of AF 709.
Rhoda was to be a project, by Bob, in how to make the perfect woman who doesn't talk back. The show was billed as a comedy, though ratings were poor. Bob Cummings, who played MacDonald, asked to be written out halfway through the season, exiting in the 21st episode. Newmar received praise for her comedic timing.
In Star Trek, Rhoda is also said to be an inspiration behind the character of Data. My Living Doll has also been credited as responsible for making the phrase Does Not Compute popular in media. Though Seven of Nine is quite far removed from the docile, man-pleasing Rhoda, both characters are projects of a sort. Rhoda is MacDonald's pet project, while Seven would become Janeway's.


FWIW, it's also been suggested that both were inspired by the IBM 709.
https://x.com/MattBaume/status/1648026790722686977

So the "Seven of Nine" vs "709" naming similarity is interesting and seems plausible at least. But the linked quote here ends on suggesting thematic similarity in the character themselves, not just their name; which I find a strained argument. Given that androids are not real, and all of the referenced shows take place in a world where human-like androids are not commonplace at all; that alone justifies the androids being considered to be experimental/rare projects, without there needing to be any specific reference from one work to another.

Possibly.
Peter J. Greenwood from Chertok TV was a semi-regular poster on the HobbyTalk forum, especially in relation to model building, regularly sharing behind-the-scenes photos from the Chertok archive. He claimed that Seven of Nine was (probably) an homage to Julie Newmar's character, Rhoda AF 709

You know it wouldn't be the first time our shows have been given a
nod..from My Living Doll..Rhoda AF 709 as played by Julie Newmar..then
Star Trek Voyager has the Borg robot girl 7 0f 9..or the fact the
Voyager's profile is based on Uncle Martin's ship..and George is a fan
of My Favorite Martian..soo yep it could well be..and for that tip of
the hat I'm sure Jack Chertok would smile a wide smile..

and

Yes Sony used a Props replica of our ship in MIB2..it was built by
Props Guy Steven Stockbarger..and he did a great job (mind you the
front of a V shuttle and more are present.) we gave the Ok for it.
And in the truth can now be told dept..My friend Doug Drexler designer
for many Star Trek shows came clean recently...
The Starship Voyager...look carefully at your Uncle Martin ship
model..looking?
Ok, the profile of the Voyager is based on our spaceship, it was one
of a dozen designs, it was done as a throw away...but they picked it
and the rest is history.
Oh and that's not the only Chertok Conection to Star Trek
Voyager...The Borg Girl...We made a show called "My Living Doll" with
Julie Newmar as the Robot girl Rhoda..who's model was AF709...and the
Borg Girl is 7 of 9..yes the writers were fans. :wave:
https://www.hobbytalk.com/posts/3808127/

